# How can I define the following function for arbitray values of the arguments?

Tags: function-construction, numerics, fitting, evaluation, argument-patterns

Consider the following function

```
a[m_, l_] = 1/Log[m/l];
```

with this function I define

```
c[NN_, r_, l_] := cc /. Solve[NN == (1/a[1/r, l] - cc), cc][[1]]
```

the things to keep in mind are these. The variable `l` is meant to be taken around 0.3 . `NN` is supposed to be an integer and for fixed `l` c will get smaller and smaller as NN-s increases. What I am interested at is to define a function that obtains for fixed `l` and `r` the value of `NN` that makes `c` smallest and positive. In order to do this I defined this

```
NNfun[r_, l_] := (NNN = 0; While[c[NNN, r, l] > 0, NNN++]; NNN - 1)
```

and it actually does the job well. Nonetheless I have a problem when I use this function to make a fit. I want to feed `NNfun` to another function in order to make a fit. The function I have in reality is more complicated than what I will show here, and the data I present here is not the data I have in but it is enough to make my point and to simplify the discussion. Thus, defining some random data points

```
data = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[{-1, 0}]}, {i, 1, 30}];
dataError = Table[RandomReal[{0, 0.001}], {i, 1, 30}];
```

and defining the following function

```
fun[r_, l_] :=Sum[a[1/r, l]^n, {n, 1, NNfun[r,l]+1}]
```

I do a fit

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, fun[x, l] , {l}, x, Weights -> 1/dataError^2];
%["BestFitParameters"]
%%["EstimatedVariance"]
```

When I did this I obtained some numbers that made no sense to me. Eventually I think I discovered what is the issue behind. What I noticed is that

```
NNfun[r, l]
```

outputs -1 for an arbitrary value of `r` and `l`. The reason is that the `While` in the function does nothing for arbytray `r` and `l` so the output just takes the init value for `NNN` that I set which is 0 so the output is of course -1. as a consequence, when I evaluated

```
fun[r, l]
```

in the function I feed to NonlinearModelFit I actually am feeding 0, so that what I obtain is equivalent to doing

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, 0 , {l}, x, Weights -> 1/dataError^2];
%["BestFitParameters"]
%%["EstimatedVariance"]
```

So i finally arrive at my question, how can I define a function that just as `NNfun` above finds me the value of `NN` that makes `c` smallest and positive and that I can use in the fit function? that is that I can evaluate it for arbitrary `r` and `l` without obtaining nonsense. Or better, how can I modify my definitions so that I can use `NNfun` in the fit?

Answer (score 1):

I have already answered on the main issue for your [follow-up question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/208056/280).

Here I wish to note that your `data` have non-positive values for the ordinate, while the function is positive in the given `data` range `0 < x < 1`:

```
fun[r_Real, l_Real] := Sum[a[1/r, l]^n, {n, 1, NNfun[r, l] + 1}]
Show[Plot[fun[x, .3], {x, 0, 1}], ListPlot[data], PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: plot]

How could you expect to obtain a good fit for such data?