# How to have NonlinearModelFit not evaluate a function too early?

Tags: function-construction, numerics, mathematical-optimization, evaluation, argument-patterns

This is a follow up of my previous question [How can I define the following function for arbitray values of the arguments?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206149/how-can-i-define-the-following-function-for-arbitray-values-of-the-arguments) that received no attention so here I will try to be more concise with the problem without drowning in details.

So here we go. What I wanna do is a fit. I have a function that has two arguments `fun[x, l]`. `x` will be the x axis of the fit, so to speak and `l` is the parameter I want to fit.

To this end I use

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, fun[x, l] , {l}, x, Weights -> 1/dataError^2];
%["BestFitParameters"]
%%["EstimatedVariance"]
```

The function `fun` uses another function `NNfun[x, l]` where the first argument will be used as the x axis in `NonlinearModelFit` and I again have `l` the parameter I want to fit.

I ran into some nonsensical things while trying the fit above and eventually I realized what the issue was. The issue is that `NNfun[x, l]` does what it is supposed to do when I feed it actual values of `x` or `l` but when I evaluate say `NNfun[0.1, l]` it always returns -1 (the details of why -1 are given in my previous question I mention above).

Thus when I fed `fun[x, l]` to `NonlinearModelFit` I was feeding the wrong function because `NNfun[x, l]` always evaluated to -1, which is not correct. That is, the problem is that this function only works for actual values of its arguments, but if `l` is left arbitrary, which is what I need to perform the fit, it doesn't.

I have tried to define `NNfun[x, l]` alternatively but so far I have not come to anything that works. So I wonder if there is a way to feed `NNfun[x, l]` somehow "freezing" the evaluation so  that NonlinearModelFit fits the function I want to fit. Can I somehow achieve this?

Comment: So, in order to understand why the function returns `-1` one needs to read another lengthy post?

Comment: @yarchik yeah, I mean, the point of this post is to condense the other one. because it received no attention. The reason in a nutshell is that I use a while loop in NNfun where I initialize a variable and if I do not give actual values of the parameter s to NNfun the while loop doesnt do anything useful and the output value is the initialized value which is -1.

Answer (score 3):

You should define your objective function using the "black box" pattern in order to prevent symbolic processing by `NonlinearModelFit`:

```
fun[r_?NumericQ, l_?NumericQ] :=Sum[a[1/r, l]^n, {n, 1, NNfun[r,l]+1}]
```

Actually such questions were asked already many times on this site, see this FAQ answer:

- [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037)

This pattern also mentioned in the official Documentation in some places:

- On the Docs page for `NumericQ`: ["Define a function that only evaluates when its argument is numeric: ..."](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html#869787512)
- On the Docs page for `FindRoot`: ["Specify the Jacobian for a "black-box" function: ..."](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html#58854240)

A Wolfram Quick Answers artice:

- ["How do I use `?NumericQ` to affect order of evaluation?"](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502)